# SQL Variable current date - 1 day

Tags: sql, database, variables, sybase

I have a variable that retrieves the current date.

```
select
  dateformat(getdate(), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.SSSSSS')
```

What i want to do is change this so it inserts the current date - 1 day.

Does anyone know the best way around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want `DATEADD`:

```
select dateformat(dateadd(dd, -1, getdate()), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.SSSSSS')
```